# How to remove response time, samplers from the jmeter results

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I am trying to remove response time and samplers from my Jmeter results in summary report. I know we can do it with help of Filter Result options, but it just removes the label or samplers and it still shows the and adds up its response time. But suppose I have bunch of samplers in a transaction controller and I want to remove or ignore the response time of some of samplers (I can not disable them, I have send them I just don't want to consider their response time) then how should I do it? is there a way?

Comment: Save them results into .jtl file standard way, then process it whatever you like (it's essentially a csv), then visualize - in JMeter or wherever else you like. That's basically the way very Filter Results call format suggests you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe there is an easy way of excluding Transaction Controller's children from the .jtl file.

You can visualize the results using i.e. [BM.Sense](https://sense.blazemeter.com/) analysis solution, in `Composite Timeline Analysis` panel you have the possibility to choose which sampler(s) to display so you can filter out the results you're not interested in

[image]

If your goal is to execute the request but not to display it in the results you can add a [JSR223 PostProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PostProcessor) as a child of the request you would like to omit and put the following code into "Script" area:

```
prev.setIgnore()
```

This way the sampler(s) in the JSR223 PostProcessor's [scope](https://wiki.apache.org/jmeter/UserManual/ScopingRules) will be excluded from any form of reports:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I think second option will work for me. I have a question, when I use prev.setIgnore() on a request and send request from Jmeter, server and DB will work on that request but I wont see it on my results. Right? Just want to make sure.

Comment: Yes. Have you tried to read the answer? `execute the request but not to display it in the results`

Comment: Just wanted confirm. Thanks for the help :)